# sorting rows in matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix, tapply

I have a simple matrix in r, produced with tapply:

```
> test_fixer

H01       H02       H03       M01       M02       M03       M04       M05      
M06
N 0.2205882 0.0750000 0.4027778 0.2926829 0.3207547 0.3142857 0.1627907 0.2653061 0.2285714
Y 0.3181818 0.2222222 0.2280702 0.3278689 0.3400000 0.3714286 0.2589286 0.3135593 0.2604167
```

I want to reorder this matrix so bars in a barplot appear in this order (that is, non-alphabetical!):

```
M01,M02,M03,M04,M05,M06,H01,H02,H03
```

I have tried a number of things, including something like this:

```
test_fixer[order(names(test_fixer))]
```

but gives error that argument not a vector.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your problem. An easily reproducible example would surely help.

In the topic you say that you want to sort rows, but considering the data you provide it seems like you want to sort columns?

```
test_fixer2 <- test_fixer[,c(4:9,1:3)]
```

The above code will change the columns according to your specification.

Answer (score 1):

I would split the matrix in two parts: `M1` containing only the "`M`" columns and `M2` only the "`H`" columns. After that, the submatrices can be recombined in the desired order with `cbind()`:

```
M1 <- test_fixer[,grepl("M",colnames(test_fixer))]
M2 <- test_fixer[,grepl("H",colnames(test_fixer))]
cbind(M1,M2)
#        M01       M02       M03       M04       M05       M06       H01       H02       H03
#Y 0.2926829 0.3207547 0.3142857 0.1627907 0.2653061 0.2285714 0.2205882 0.0750000 0.4027778
#N 0.3278689 0.3400000 0.3714286 0.2589286 0.3135593 0.2604167 0.3181818 0.2222222 0.2280702
```